# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar transação explicita

Tags: sql

Além da segurança qual a vantagem de usar transação explícita? Em quais situações é recomendado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Transações implícitas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Neste modo, o servidor irá garantir que todas as operações sejam realizadas dentro de uma transação.

Em geral são usadas para que o desenvolvedor não precise se preocupar com a lógica de tratamento transacional e tenha que repeti-la em por todo o código.

Porém, a tendência é a degradação do desempenho, pois transações são mais "caras" do ponto de vista computacional já que o banco de dados precisa realizar várias verificações adicionais e há maior probabilidade de ocorrerem *locks* e *deadlocks* em que o desenvolvedor consiga prever.

Enfim, a vantagem é em relação à facilidade de desenvolvimento ao custo do desempenho e de possíveis *locks*.

## [Transações Explícitas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175127%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Deixa a cargo do desenvolvedor iniciar e encerrar transações através de comandos:

- `BEGIN TRANS`
- `COMMIT TRANS`
- `ROLLBACK TRANS`

A desvantagem é que o desenvolvedor precisa repetir a lógica de controle em todos os pontos onde transações forem necessários.

Por outro lado, isso permite um ajuste fino do desempenho, minimizando uso de transações onde não é necessário, *locks* e *deadlocks*, além de possibilitar ao desenvolvedor analisar os casos de possíveis problemas de concorrência.

## Recomendações

Minha recomendação é usar sempre **transações explícitas** delimitando manualmente onde elas serão necessárias.

Quando o código por si só realiza operações atômicas, transações não são necessárias. Por exemplo, quando se faz apenas um comando `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` ou `SELECT`.

No entanto, quando há uma sequência de operações, então deve-se iniciar uma transação sempre englobando a menor quantidade de código possível, de forma a aumentar a eficiência do sistema de banco de dados para processar requisições concorrentes.

Answer (score 5):

Vantagens:

- Segurança em operações que envolvam várias alterações em diferentes elementos de dados, evitando que dados sejam inseridos incompletos por falhas sistêmicas;
- Em caso de falha física do equipamento, torna possível a restauração do banco de dados de forma segura até o último *checkpoint* transacional válido;
- Permite propagação correta de dados, em caso de sistemas multiusuários, organizando alterações concorrentes.

Desvantagens:

- Mais lento que uma operação simples de persistência;
- Pode causar deadlocks;
- Transações exclusivas podem indisponibilizar o banco de dados para outros usuários, que não estejam dentro do escopo da transação, consequentemente tornando o sistema lento se as operações dentro de uma transação também forem.

Recomendado usar:

- Em operações que envolva persistência de múltiplas entidades;
- Em sistemas que ocorram alterações nas informações em tempo real, e estas alterações sejam propagadas para vários usuários ao mesmo tempo.