# PreparedStatement não está funcionando

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Código que estou usando

```
PreparedStatement i = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO teste VALUES (player='teste', level_1=0, level_2=0, level_3=0, level_4=0, level_5=0, level_6=0, level_7=0, level_8=0, level_9=0, level_10=0)");
i.executeUpdate();
```

Estrutura da tabela.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apenas acontece isso com o `Insert into`, já usei esse mesmo código para criar a tabela e não deu problema nenhum, esse simplesmente não insere, qual o problema?

Não da nenhum erro, nada, simplesmente não insere.

Comment: O que aconteceu de errado? Ele dá uma SQLException? Ele não faz nada? Ele insere algo diferente do que deveria inserir? Ele conseguiu conectar na base de dados? Não vejo nada de errado no pouco código que você forneceu, talvez o problema esteja em algum outro lugar.

Comment: Coloca o nome das colunas tbm e não só o valor.

Comment: @rray Mas ele colocou. Veja a instrução SQL.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, entendi é aquele insert em formato de update, pela imagem parece que todos os valores estão em uma coluna.

Comment: @rray "esse simplesmente não insere"

Comment: Se vc copiar o insert e testar direto no banco ele funciona? ou da algum erro?

Comment: @rray funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Está usando o mysql? está utilizando transção? o auto commit está ligado?

Comment: sim, não sei o que é isso, e o auto commit eu deixei false.

Comment: faz um teste, deixa o auto commit `true`, ai sempre que vc mandar uma consulta no banco será aplicada na hora. Já com o auto commit `false` vc precisa dizer ao banco para efetuar a operação (insert, update, delete) com sucesso use `commit` e para falha `rollback`.

Comment: @rray deixei true e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Esta pergunta está muito superficial, é preciso mais informação.

Comment: @Delfino ja foi resolvido.

Comment: @LeonardoSnt, entendo, mas seria interessante ajustar a pergunta, mantendo assim o site organizado. Facilitando para que outros consigam acesso a informação.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69103/preparedstatement-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando#comment141193_69103) foi possível descobrir que o problema não era o seu código mas a configuração do banco, o `autocommit` estava desligado (por isso nenhum exception foi lançada), dessa forma instruções de escrita (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) são somente aplicadas no banco de dados após a chamada de um `commit` para sucesso ou `rollback` para falha, sem a chamada de algum desses dois comandos a consulta fica em um estado de 'rascunho' somente quem realizou a operação ve o resultado.

Leitura recomendada:

[Como habilitar o autocommit pelo workbench ou phpmyadmin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83439/91)

[Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar transação explicita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22277/91)

[MySQL Transaction Quando? Como? Porque?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91)

[Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91)

Comment: Obrigado, depois dou uma lida nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim:

```
PreparedStatement i = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO teste (player, level_1, level_2, level_3, level_4, level_5, level_6, level_7, level_8, level_9, level_10) VALUES ('teste', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)");
i.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: A mesma coisa, não inseriu.