# Adicionar dados a uma tabela MySQL, com PHP. O que há de errado?

Tags: php, mysql

Inicialmente, sou novato em PHP e SQL, então peguem leve se tiver barbeiragem no código. Estou só testando a integração PHP e MySQL, aproveitei uma tabela de exemplo de um livro e fiz uma página html rápida para passar os parâmetros.

**HTML: (index.html)**

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <form action="add.php">
        <p>Nome<input name="nome" type="text"/>
        <p>Principal Ingrediente<input name="principal" type="text"/>
        <p>Quantidade<input name="quant1" type="number"/>
        <p>Ingrediente Secundário<input name="segundo" type="text"/>
        <p>Quantidade<input name="quant2" type="number"/>
        <p>Instrução<input name="instrucao" type="text"/>
        <p><input type="submit"/>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**PHP: (add.php)**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
        $nome = $_GET['nome'];
        $principal = $_GET['principal'];
        $quant1 = $_GET['quant1'];
        $segundo = $_GET['segundo'];
        $quant2 = $_GET['quant2'];
        $instrucao = $_GET['instrucao'];
        $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'Another2/', 'drinks');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO drinkfaceis(nome, principal, quant1, segundo, quant2, instrucoes) 
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if(!$stmt){
            echo 'erro na consulta: '. $db->errno .' - '. $db->error;
        }

        echo $nome;
        echo $principal;
        echo $quant1;
        echo $segundo;
        echo $quant2;
        echo $instrucao;

        $stmt->bind_param('ssisib', $nome, $principal, $quant1, $segundo, $quant2, $instrucao);
        $stmt->execute();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script SQL:**

```
CREATE DATABASE drinks;
USE drinks;
CREATE TABLE drinkfaceis
(
    nome        VARCHAR(20),
    principal   VARCHAR(20),
    quant1      INT(10),
    segundo     VARCHAR(20),
    quant2      INT(10),
    instrucoes  BLOB
);
```

Ao testar não dá erro nenhum, ele escreve o valor das variáveis (que coloquei só pra testar), mas quando vou no phpMyAdmin e olho a tabela o dado não foi inserido.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27589/discussion-between-rray-and-leonardo-vilarinho).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E mais uma vez o código estava correto, o problema era o `autocommit` desativado.

Quando ele está desligado você é obrigado a dizer para o banco que aquele comando (uma DML insert/update/delete) deve ser executado de forma permanente, isso pode ser feito de várias formas atraves do php, com o [commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) para sucesso e [rollback()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php) para cancelar a instrução.

---

Leitura recomendada:

[MySQL Transaction Quando? Como? Porque?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14774/91)

[Para que serve uma MySQL Transaction?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/91)

---

Para ligar o autocommit do banco com o **workbanch** acesse o menu:

`Server>Option file` na guia `General`, procure a opção `transaction` e marque `autocommit`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PHPMyAdmin**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]