# SqlUpdate não altera dados no banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mvc

Obs: Várias pessoas não conseguiram resolver essa pergunta e **marcaram minha pergunta como erroneamente duplicada por causa de uma resposta em uma outra pergunta parecida com essa mas a resposta não me ajudo em nada**.

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC (Model-view-controller) e está ocorrendo o problema de não alterar os atributos das pessoaa. Quando vou alterar clicando no meu botão salvar para salvar minhas alterações exibe a mensagem "alterado com sucesso" mas não altera realmente!

Classe VideoPessoa incluindo os botoes de salvar e de alterar, da camada view:

```
 public VideoPessoa() {
            initComponents();

            new Conexao();
            pessoaController = new PessoaController();
            pessoa = new Pessoa();
            this.carregarPessoas();
             this.novaPessoa();
            this.habilitarCampos();

        }

    public boolean alterarPessoa() {
            pessoa.setCodigo( Integer.parseInt(this.txtCodigo.getText()));
            pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
            pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
            pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
            pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
            pessoa.setSexo(this.txtSexo.getText());
            pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
            pessoa.setCelular(this.txtCelular.getText());
            pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
            pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());

            if (pessoaController.alterar(pessoa)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro alterado com sucesso!");
                 this.desabilitarCampos();
                this.carregarPessoas();
            } else {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao alterar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

            return true;

        }

private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

      if (!alterarPessoa){
              salvarPessoa();
          } else {
              alterarPessoa();
          }

    }                                         

    private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       habilitarCampos();
     recuperarPessoas();
     alterarPessoa = true;

    }
```

Classe PessoaController:

```
public class PessoaController {

    private final PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;

    public PessoaController() {
        pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();

    }

 public boolean alterar( Pessoa pessoa ) {
        boolean retorno;

        retorno = pessoaDAO.alterar(pessoa);

        System.out.println("Pessoa: "+pessoa); 

        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe PessoaDAO, incluindo o método de alterar pessoas:

```
public class PessoaDAO {

    private Connection con;

    private final String SQLSELECT = " SELECT  codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF,  uf, cidade FROM PESSOA";

    private final String SQLUPDATE = " UPDATE pessoa"
            + " SET nome = ?, "
            + " endereco = ?, "
            + " bairro   = ?, "
            + " sexo     = ?, "
            + " telefone = ?, "
            + " celular  = ?, "
            + " CPF      = ?, "
            + " uf       =?, "
            + " cidade   =? "
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private PreparedStatement sqlSelect, sqlUpdate;

    public PessoaDAO() {

        con = Conexao.getConnection();
        try {
            sqlSelect = con.prepareStatement(SQLSELECT);
            sqlUpdate = con.prepareStatement(SQLUPDATE);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public Pessoa getPessoaPeloCodigo(int codigo) {

        Pessoa pessoa = null;
 try (
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO)
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, codigo);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (!rs.next()) return null; // Não encontrou.
                // Instancia a nova pessoa.
                //Instancia o novo filme
                pessoa = new Pessoa();

                //Seta as informações no filme
                pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
                pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pessoa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                pessoa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                pessoa.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                pessoa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                pessoa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
                pessoa.setCPF(rs.getString("CPF"));

                pessoa.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                pessoa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return pessoa;
    }

public boolean alterar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        boolean retorno = false;
        try {
            sqlUpdate.setInt(1, pessoa.getCodigo());
            sqlUpdate.setString(2,pessoa.getNome());
            sqlUpdate.setString(3, pessoa.getEndereco());
            sqlUpdate.setString(4, pessoa.getBairro());
            sqlUpdate.setString(5, pessoa.getSexo());
            sqlUpdate.setString(6, pessoa.getTelefone());
            sqlUpdate.setString(7, pessoa.getCelular());
            sqlUpdate.setString(8, pessoa.getCPF());
            sqlUpdate.setString(9, pessoa.getUf());
            sqlUpdate.setString(10, pessoa.getCidade());


            sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();

            retorno = true;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Verificou o autocommit do banco se está ativado?, Relacionada: [prepared statement não funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69103/91) ou [como habilitar no workbench](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83439/91)

Comment: @rray verifiquei sim e está ativado! Esses dois links não resolveu minha pergunta.

Comment: @rray Verifiquei e estava ligado sim e esses seus dois links não resolveu meu problema!

Comment: No seu alterar, mude `sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();` por : `sqlUpdate.executeUpdate(SQLUPDATE);`

Comment: Deu erro : `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,  endereco = ?,  bairro   = ?,  sexo     = ?,  telefone = ?,  celular  = ?,  C' at line 1 `

Comment: To tentando procurar a linha mas não encontro nenhum erro

Comment: Da um sysout em `SQLUPDATE` e coloca o retorno aqui

Comment: sysout antes do sqlupadte=  `PessoaPessoa{nome=ee, endereco=eee, bairro=eee, sexo=, telefone=4444, celular=44, CPF=6666, codigo=44, cidade=eee, uf=jj, pessoa=null `

Comment: depois do sysout: `Pessoa: Pessoa{nome=ee, endereco=eee, bairro=eee, sexo=, telefone=4444, celular=44, CPF=6666, codigo=44, cidade=eee, uf=jj, pessoa=null} `

Answer (score 0):

Parece que os parâmetros passados não estão na ordem certa para realizar o update, veja:

```
UPDATE pessoa SET
    nome = ?,    <--- 1
    endereco = ?,<--- 2
    bairro   = ?,<--- 3
    sexo     = ?,<--- 4
    telefone = ?,<--- 5
    celular  = ?,<--- 6
    CPF      = ?,<--- 7
    uf       = ?,<--- 8
    cidade   = ? <--- 9
WHERE codigo = ? <--- 10
```

Olhe os binds agora, o `codigo` deve ser o número 10 e não número 1, pois a primeira interrogação faz refêrencia ao campo `nome`

```
sqlUpdate.setInt(1, pessoa.getCodigo());
sqlUpdate.setString(2,pessoa.getNome());
sqlUpdate.setString(3, pessoa.getEndereco());
sqlUpdate.setString(4, pessoa.getBairro());
sqlUpdate.setString(5, pessoa.getSexo());
sqlUpdate.setString(6, pessoa.getTelefone());
sqlUpdate.setString(7, pessoa.getCelular());
sqlUpdate.setString(8, pessoa.getCPF());
sqlUpdate.setString(9, pessoa.getUf());
sqlUpdate.setString(10, pessoa.getCidade());
```

O código final deve ficar assim:

```
sqlUpdate.setString(1,pessoa.getNome());
sqlUpdate.setString(2, pessoa.getEndereco());
sqlUpdate.setString(3, pessoa.getBairro());
sqlUpdate.setString(4, pessoa.getSexo());
sqlUpdate.setString(5, pessoa.getTelefone());
sqlUpdate.setString(6, pessoa.getCelular());
sqlUpdate.setString(7, pessoa.getCPF());
sqlUpdate.setString(8, pessoa.getUf());
sqlUpdate.setString(9, pessoa.getCidade());
sqlUpdate.setInt(10, pessoa.getCodigo());
int linhasAfetadas = sqlUpdate.executeUpdate(SQLUPDATE);

if(linhasAfetadas > 0){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Fiz como você falou e não deu certo!

Comment: @IgorContini, Você trocou todos os indíces? qual erro apareceu?

Comment: Caiu a internet aqui.. Coloquei o código final e o `sqlUpdate.executeUpdate(SQLUPDATE); ` ficou sublinhado com linha vermelha indicando erro e exibindo a mensagem: unreachable statement!

Comment: @IgorContini, veja agora, qualquer coisa remova o if-else para testar.

Comment: Troquei todos os índices  a 1 até o 10 e o código ficou com o índice 10. Erro: ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,  endereco = ?,  bairro   = ?,  sexo     = ?,  telefone = ?,  celular  = ?,  C' at line 1 `

Comment: removi o if e o else e deu esse mesmo: ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,  endereco = ?,  bairro   = ?,  sexo     = ?,  telefone = ?,  celular  = ?,  C' at line `

Comment: @IgorContini tem algum estranha na `?` do nome ... `nome = ?,` esse é o trecho com problema ...

Comment: Pior mesmo.. já tinha notado isso e agora lancei uma nova pergunta!