# Erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC (Model-view-controller) e está ocorrendo o problema de não alterar os dados das pessoas. Quando vou alterar os dados da pessoa exibe a seguinte mensagem: "Erro ao alterar dados!".

Classe VideoPessoa, da camada view:

```
public class VideoPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    PessoaController pessoaController;
    Pessoa pessoa;




    /**
     * Creates new form Pessoa
     */
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        this.carregarPessoas();
         this.novaPessoa();
        this.habilitarCampos();

    }

public boolean alterarPessoa() {
        pessoa.setCodigo( Integer.parseInt(this.txtCodigo.getText()));
        pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
        pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
        pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
        pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
        pessoa.setSexo(this.txtSexo.getText());
        pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
        pessoa.setCelular(this.txtCelular.getText());
        pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
        pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());

        if (pessoaController.alterar(pessoa)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro alterado com sucesso!");
             this.desabilitarCampos();
            this.carregarPessoas();
        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao alterar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Classe PessoaController:

public class PessoaController {

```
private final PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;


public PessoaController() {
    pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();


}



public boolean alterar( Pessoa pessoa ) {
        boolean retorno;



        retorno = pessoaDAO.alterar(pessoa);

        System.out.println("Pessoa: "+pessoa); 

        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe PessoaDAO, incluindo o método de alterar pessoas:

```
public class PessoaDAO {

    private Connection con;

    private final String SQLINSERT = " INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

    private final String SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO = "SELECT codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade"
            + " FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo=? ";

    private final String SQLSELECT = " SELECT  codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF,  uf, cidade FROM PESSOA";

    private final String SQLUPDATE = " UPDATE pessoa"
            + " SET nome = ?, "
            + " endereco = ?, "
            + " bairro   = ?, "
            + " sexo     = ?, "
            + " telefone = ?, "
            + " celular  = ?, "
            + " CPF      = ?, "
            + " uf       =?, "
            + " cidade   =?, "
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private final String SQLDELETE = "DELETE FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private PreparedStatement psInsert, sqlPessoaPeloCodigo, sqlSelect, sqlUpdate, sqlDelete;

    public PessoaDAO() {

        con = Conexao.getConnection();
        try {
            psInsert = con.prepareStatement(SQLINSERT);
            sqlPessoaPeloCodigo = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO);
            sqlSelect = con.prepareStatement(SQLSELECT);
            sqlUpdate = con.prepareStatement(SQLUPDATE);
            sqlDelete = con.prepareStatement(SQLDELETE);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

public Pessoa getPessoaPeloCodigo(int codigo) {    

    Pessoa pessoa = null;    

    try {    
        // Apenas mudei a declaração e a inicialização para dentro do método.     
PreparedStatement sqlPessoaPeloCodigo = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO);  
        sqlPessoaPeloCodigo.setInt(1, codigo);    
        ResultSet rs = sqlPessoaPeloCodigo.executeQuery();    

        if (rs.next()) {    
            //Instancia a nova pessoa    
            pessoa = new Pessoa();    

            //Seta as informações na pessoa    
            pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));    
            pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));    
            pessoa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));    
            pessoa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));    
            pessoa.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));    
            pessoa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));    
            pessoa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));    
            pessoa.setCPF(rs.getString("CPF"));      
            pessoa.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));    
            pessoa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));    

        }    
  // fechando o resultSet e o PreparedStatement   
        rs.close();  
        sqlPessoaPeloCodigo.close();  



    } catch (SQLException ex) {    
        Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);    
    }    
    return pessoa;    
}    

public boolean alterar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        boolean retorno = false;

        try {
            sqlUpdate = con.prepareStatement(SQLUPDATE);

            sqlUpdate.setString(1,pessoa.getNome());
            sqlUpdate.setString(2, pessoa.getEndereco());
            sqlUpdate.setString(3, pessoa.getBairro());
            sqlUpdate.setString(4, pessoa.getSexo());
            sqlUpdate.setString(5, pessoa.getTelefone());
            sqlUpdate.setString(6, pessoa.getCelular());
            sqlUpdate.setString(7, pessoa.getCPF());
            sqlUpdate.setString(8, pessoa.getUf());
            sqlUpdate.setString(9, pessoa.getCidade());
            sqlUpdate.setInt(10, pessoa.getCodigo());




            sqlUpdate.executeUpdate(SQLUPDATE);



            retorno = true;



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Erro:

```
Conexao obtida!
PessoaPessoa{nome=ee, endereco=eee, bairro=eee, sexo=, telefone=4444, celular=44, CPF=6666, codigo=46, cidade=eee, uf=jj, pessoa=null}
out 28, 2015 4:38:04 PM dao.PessoaDAO alterar
GRAVE: null
Pessoa: Pessoa{nome=ee, endereco=eee, bairro=eee, sexo=, telefone=4444, celular=44, CPF=6666, codigo=46, cidade=eee, uf=jj, pessoa=null}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?  endereco = ?  bairro   = ?  sexo     = ?  telefone = ? celular  = ?  CPF     ' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
    at dao.PessoaDAO.alterar(PessoaDAO.java:151)
    at controller.PessoaController.alterar(PessoaController.java:47)
    at view.VideoPessoa.alterarPessoa(VideoPessoa.java:423)
    at view.VideoPessoa.btnAlterarActionPerformed(VideoPessoa.java:346)
    at view.VideoPessoa.access$200(VideoPessoa.java:25)
    at view.VideoPessoa$3.actionPerformed(VideoPessoa.java:124)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Pessoa: Pessoa{nome=ee, endereco=eee, bairro=eee, sexo=, telefone=4444, celular=44, CPF=6666, codigo=46, cidade=eee, uf=jj, pessoa=null}
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 20 segundos)
```

Comment: Não tem essa virgula aqui: `cidade   =?,`

Comment: Eu já tirei essa virgula e continua dando erro!

Comment: @rray Você não consegui resolver minha duvida..

Comment: Não conseguiu resolver? ainda é o mesmo problema ou apareceu outro erro?

Comment: Você não consegui resolver essa pergunta : [ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94958/sqlupdate-n%C3%A3o-altera-dados-no-banco-de-dados ] . Você marco minha pergunta como duplicada por causa da sua resposta em uma outra pergunta parecida com essa mas a sua resposta não me ajudo em nada. Logo depois lancei a mesma pergunta com titulo diferente pois não resolveu minha dúvida e teve varias pessoas que marcaram como duplicada e como consequência não posso publicar perguntas para resolver minha dúvida!

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta e adicionar os novos detalhes ou testes que fez.

Comment: Eu ja fiz os testes e agora to querendo publicá-la novamente mas seu publica-la novamente vão marca como duplicada e já estou bloqueado por causa daquelas duas perguntas duplicadas!

Comment: Nem editar essa pergunta você consegue?

Comment: Fui olha e nem edita consigo!

Comment: Quando vc clica no [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/95183/edit) aparece o que?

Comment: Fui clicar no seu editar e deu certo, mas no meu editar não havia dado certo não. O que vou editar na minha pergunta?

Comment: Colocao o que vc já fez e não deu certo ou o que vc fez de mudou o erro, atualize o código, mensagem de erro.

Comment: Vou fazer isso então.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, acho que o erro está na `Classe PessoaDAO`, neste trecho:

```
        sqlUpdate.setInt(10, pessoa.getCodigo());

 ---->  sqlUpdate.executeUpdate(SQLUPDATE);  <-----

        retorno = true;
```

Você carregou os valores no objeto sqlUpdate, mas depois você informa o que o execute deve rodar, não precisa pois você já informou isto logo acima ao instanciar a classe no objeto, tente trocar a linha por:

```
sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

---

`Já tentei isso já e exibe a mensagem "alterado com sucesso" mas simplesmente não altera! – Igor Contini`

O ideal é debugar, mas faça este teste, coloca abaixo do:

```
pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());
Integer codigo = pessoa.getCodigo();
String nome = pessoa.getNome();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, codigo+' - '+nome);
```

Comment: Já tentei isso já e exibe a mensagem "alterado com sucesso" mas simplesmente não altera!

Comment: Você está debugando a execução ?, tem certeza que no **VideoPessoa**, as informações estão sendo carregadas no objeto **pessoa** ?, se não sabe debugar passe um alert com os valores de **pessoa** após seta-los no **alterarPessoa**

Comment: Como assim? Como passo um alert? Sou iniciante em java ainda..

Comment: Onde que se coloca o `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pessoa.get('codigo')+pessoa.get('nome'));` ??? Eu coloquei debaixo da mensagem " alterado com sucesso"  mas dá vários erros!

Comment: Editei a resposta, adapta o tipo de dados que informei para o que você usou na classe Pessoa e verifica se os nome de objeto e função estão corretos.

Comment: Estão corretos sim e quando faço os teste que passou, não altera realmente e exibe a mensagem alterado com sucesso!

Comment: Se o texto ```codigo+' - '+nome``` veio vazio, então o erro está na atribuição de dados vindos do formulário ```pessoa.setCodigo( Integer.parseInt(this.txtCodigo.getText()));```, verifique se usou os nomes certos, ```txtCodigo``` tem que ser um campo do ```form``` e verifique se a syxtax está certa.

Comment: Verifiquei e estão certos!  O erro esta aqui: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?  endereco = ?  bairro   = ?  sexo     = ?  telefone = ? celular  = ?  CPF     ' at line 1 `

Comment: Mas este erro não sumiu depois que passou a usar ```sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();``` ?

Comment: Opa sumiu sim! , por que?

Comment: Tenta incluir um registro na mão no teu banco, usa o texto da query e subistitui os ? manualmente.

Comment: Inseri e alterei manualmente! O problema esta no código mesmo..

Comment: Bem ninguém resolveu a minha dúvida..